# datagridview comboboxes view all contents at once, drop down gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview of 4 columns and 17 rows, column one is numbers 1-16 and columns 2-4 are comboboxes all with the same values. These comboboxes have lists up to 100 items in them. I would like to display these items in grid pattern, maybe 10x10 or something, so the user can see all the items at once and choose one instead of one long list to scroll through.

This is one of the columns that I have to construct the comboboxes as you can see it has a lot of items.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn DCSfreq = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
DCSfreq.DataPropertyName = "DCS (Hz)";
DCSfreq.HeaderText = "DCS (Hz)";
String[] DCS = { "", "23", "25", "26", "31", "32", "43", "47", "51", "54", "65", "71", "72", "73", "74", "114", "115", "116", "125", "131", "132", "134", "143", "152", "155", "156", "162", "165",
"172", "174", "205", "223", "226", "243", "244", "245", "251", "261", "263", "265", "271", "306", "311", "315", "331", "343", "346", "351", "364", 
"365", "371", "411", "412", "413", "423", "431", "432", "445", "464", "465", "466", "503", "506", "516", "532", "546", "565", "606", "612", "624",
"627", "631", "632", "654", "662", "664", "703", "712", "723", "731", "732", "734", "743", "754" };
DCSfreq.Items.AddRange(DCS);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(DCSfreq);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use a nested `DataGridView` instead of `ComboBox` like this:

```
private DataGridView childDgv = new DataGridView();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parentDgv.CellClick += parentDgv_CellClick;
    parentDgv.Columns["DCS (Hz)"].ReadOnly = true; // uneditable

    Set10x10Data(childDgv);　// set 10 x 10 data to the child DataGridView
    childDgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    childDgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;

    childDgv.CellClick += childDgv_CellClick;
    childDgv.Visible = false;

    parentDgv.Controls.Add(childDgv);
}

void parentDgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "DCS (Hz)")
    {
        // Show child DataGridView under the clicked cell
        Rectangle dgvRectangle = parentDgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
        childDgv.Location = new Point(dgvRectangle.X, dgvRectangle.Y + 20);
        childDgv.CurrentCell = childDgv[0, 0];
        childDgv.Visible = true;
    }
}

void childDgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    parentDgv.CurrentCell.Value = childDgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    childDgv.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, worked out good. Just had to adapt it a little bit and add somethings just for my particular program.